# sorting ng-repeat on a dynamic array with angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of data that gets populated dynamically via a socket event. However I can't sort the array properly with angular's `ng-repeat`:

```
socket.on('twitter:item', function(data){
    var item = data;

    item.time = moment(data.time).valueOf();
    item.date = formatTime(data.time);

    $scope.twitter.push(item);
});


<li ng-repeat="item in twitter | orderBy:time:true">
    <a href>{{item.title}}</a> - {{item.time}} {{item.date}}
</li>
```

The html always shows the most recent at the bottom of the ordered list...I want it at the top (thus the `orderBy:time:true` (or `false`) where `time` is milliseconds. Neither of which work.

Comment: What's the value of model 'reverse'?

Comment: i messed up reading the docs. but it is either `true` or `false` (updated post)

Comment: Try `<li ng-repeat="item in twitter | orderBy:'time':true">`

Comment: that was it. make that the answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<li ng-repeat="item in twitter | orderBy:'time':true">`.

`orderBy` accepts an expression string as its first argument. It will be evaluated to a value.

And `time` will be evaluated as `undefeind` since it's not existed in scope.

Use single quotation to make `'time'` evaluated as string.